# Mockito test framework

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

Good evening, first time faced with mock objects, I tryed to test my application but nothing happened. I should test the work of ATM. I have got 2 interfaces which are not implemented (Account and Card) and one class.
ATM (which has got empty methods). My task was too implement methods in class ATM. But not to change methods.

So here is my code, which can't be tested.

**1)Interface Card:**

```
    package myatm;
    public interface Card {
    public boolean isBlocked(); // checks whther card is blocked or not
    public Account getAccount(); // returns the balance connected with this card
    public boolean checkPin(int pinCode);     // checks the property of password
    }
```

**2)Interface Account:**

```
  package myatm;
  public interface Account  {
  public double getBalance(); // returns current balance
  public double withdrow(double amount);   // returns the sum which was taken.
   }
```

**3)Class ATM :**

```
 package myatm;
 public class ATM {
public double money;

ATM(double moneyInATM){      //we can set up the number of money in ATM
money=moneyInATM;

}


 public void setATM (ATM atm){ 
 this.atm =atm;   
}


public double getMoneyInATM() { //
return atm.checkBalance();
}
// checks pin code and card status(blocked or not)
// if blocked should send exception
// if pin is not correct should send exception too
public boolean validateCard(Card card, int pinCode){ 
boolean ret = false;
if ((card.checkPin(pinCode)==false) && (card.isBlocked()==false)){
 ret=false;
}
else {
 if((card.checkPin(pinCode)==true) && (card.isBlocked()==true))
     ret = true;
}
return ret; }
Account acc = null;
//returns the total ammount of money 
public double checkBalance(){
  return acc.getBalance();
}
 ATM atm = new ATM(10500);
// method which is taking money from the account.
//Should check if sum is less then money in atm
public double getCash(double amount){
    double sum=amount;
if(atm.checkBalance()>acc.getBalance()){
    sum=(acc.getBalance()-sum);
}
else if(atm.checkBalance()<acc.getBalance()){
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not enough money in ATM");
}
else if (sum>acc.getBalance()){
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not enought money on your account");

}
return sum;    
}}
```

**4)Class MyATM:**

```
 package myatm;

    public class MyATM {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    double moneyInATM = 1000;
    ATM atm = new ATM(moneyInATM);
    Card card = null;
    atm.validateCard(card, 1234);
    atm.checkBalance();
    atm.getCash(999.99);        
    }
    }
```

And here is my test I tried to write for one method but it doesn't work. Please try to give me an idea of what I did wrong.

**5) class which includes Mockito:**

```
 package myatm;

import static java.util.jar.Pack200.Packer.TRUE;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;



  public class ATMtest {
   ATM atm;  
  @Before
  public void setup(){
  Card card =mock(Card.class);
  Account acc = mock(Account.class);
  when(card.isBlocked()).thenReturn(Boolean.FALSE);
  when(card.checkPin(1234)).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);

 atm.setATM(atm);

 atm = new ATM(1500);   
 }

@Test
public void setBalance (double x){
Assert.assertEquals(x, atm.checkBalance());
}


}
```

Comment: you forgot the verify()-statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your code working but made the following updates:

- Removed the parameter from your test method (`@Test
  public void setBalance (double x)`).
- Added getters/setters to your ATM class because these are used for testing and good practice.
- Added the Junit runner annotation `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`
- And other updates shown in the following working code.

**ATMtest.java:**

```
package myatm;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class ATMtest {

    // Class Under Test
    ATM atm;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Card card = mock(Card.class);
        Account acc = mock(Account.class);
        when(card.isBlocked()).thenReturn(Boolean.FALSE);
        when(card.checkPin(1234)).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
        when(acc.getBalance()).thenReturn((double) 1);
        atm = new ATM(1500);
        atm.setAcc(acc);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCheckBalance() {

        /* Test */
        double result = atm.checkBalance();

        /* Asserts */
        Assert.assertEquals((double) 1, result, .001);
    }

}
```

**MyATM.java :**

```
package myatm;

public class MyATM {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double moneyInATM = 1000;
        ATM atm = new ATM(moneyInATM);
        Card card = null;
        atm.validateCard(card, 1234);
        atm.checkBalance();
        atm.getCash(999.99);
    }
}
```

**ATM.java :**

```
package myatm;

public class ATM {
    public double money;

    ATM(double moneyInATM) { // we can set up the number of money in ATM
        money = moneyInATM;

    }

    // checks pin code and card status(blocked or not)
    // if blocked should send exception
    // if pin is not correct should send exception too
    public boolean validateCard(Card card, int pinCode) {
        boolean ret = false;
        if ((card.checkPin(pinCode) == false) && (card.isBlocked() == false)) {
            ret = false;
        } else {
            if ((card.checkPin(pinCode) == true) && (card.isBlocked() == true))
                ret = true;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    Account acc = null;

    // returns the total ammount of money
    public double checkBalance() {
        return acc.getBalance();
    }

    public double getMoney() {
        return money;
    }

    public void setMoney(double money) {
        this.money = money;
    }

    public Account getAcc() {
        return acc;
    }

    public void setAcc(Account acc) {
        this.acc = acc;
    }

    // method which is taking money from the account.
    // Should check if sum is less then money in atm
    public double getCash(double amount) {
        double sum = amount;
        if (this.checkBalance() > acc.getBalance()) {
            sum = (acc.getBalance() - sum);
        } else if (this.checkBalance() < acc.getBalance()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not enough money in ATM");
        } else if (sum > acc.getBalance()) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    "Not enought money on your account");

        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

**Account.java :**

```
package myatm;

public interface Account {
    public double getBalance(); // returns current balance

    public double withdrow(double amount); // returns the sum which was taken.
}
```

**Test Results:**

[image]

Comment: how to get a green line that test is passed?

Comment: Because, everything i am getting is just assembly successfull.

Comment: ATMtest.testCheckBalance() test method is green with my code. To execute the ATMtest.testCheckBalance() highlight the test in Eclipse then right-click and choose Run as->Junit Test. I will post a screenshot later today of the successful test in the green JUnit view. @Alex Ferdison

Comment: if i am using netbeans can i do the same? because i tryed to search but couldn't found :(

Comment: everything i can this is just little line at the right corner of the sreen where i can read ATM(test) and thats all :(

Comment: javaPlease42 reply me.

Comment: I added the test results. I would suggest either switching to Eclipse or IntelliJ because I don't use Netbeans so cannot help with Netbeans. Maybe you can ask a stack overflow Netbeans question. @Alex Ferdison

Comment: I did like u sad, created project at Eclipse have the next result http://s020.radikal.ru/i714/1311/47/fee7cbccee9e.jpg

Comment: Post that picture in a new question. Some SO mate will answer that. @Alex Ferdison